# Flask-Admin: add filters on Primary keys

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, python-3.6, flask-admin

I am trying to add filter on primary keys, that's not working. I went through the source code to find that, it has been excluded:
[flask-admin/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py)

```
def scaffold_filters(self, name):
    ...
    if column.foreign_keys or column.primary_key:
        continue
    ...
```

Is there any workaround to this?
I tried using the inbuilt filters on pk but it didn't worked.

```
from back.database import Base
class MyView(ModelView):
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.column_filters = [FilterEqual('_id', '_id')]
        super().__init__(model)

class User(Base):
    _id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use the column_filters attribute of the ModelView Class

if you only want the EqualFilter it would look like this:

```
class MyView(ModelView):
   column_filters = (FilterEqual(column=User._id, name='id'),)
   def __init__(self, model):
       super().__init__(model)
```

You can also tell flask_admin to detect all possible filters, then it would look like this

```
class MyView(ModelView):
   column_filters = ('_id',)
   def __init__(self, model):
       super().__init__(model)
```

Comment: Thanks @luclechef. Basically, the reason mentioned in the question was not the reason for filters on pk not working. But your ans did solved my issue. `User._id` did worked in my existing code only. I was using only `_id`.